# how can i hold the activity till the animation gets executed

Tags: android

```
        animfadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.drawable.fade_in);

        // set animation listener
        //animBlink.setAnimationListener(this);

        opt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                l1.startAnimation(animfadein);
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondQuestion.class));
            }
        });

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="10000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

i want this animation to execute fully then the next activity should be called how can i achieve this. before the 10000 sec are been over the next activity is been called.

Answer (score 1):

Use AnimationListener:

```
    animfadein.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondQuestion.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```